# Parsing Fields from input to within a body of text

Tags: parsing, templates, input, field

Not being a coder but understand this is what it may take I have a quick question if I may.

I am writing a murder/mystery/detective fiction e book and want the reader to be the main protagonist within the book Their name, characteristics, localle, etc (all dependant on what infomation is needed) to fuel and fill the story.

I know that code can be placed within the body of the text to have the required information parsed fro the input form before downloading the book but
a. Don't know what this procedure would be called
b. What if any software or wp plugin to use
and
c.How I would go about asking for this to be created for me.

Any thoughts would be a huge help

Thanks

I looked online and asked chat gpt to no avail

Comment: This isn't really a 'parsing' question. You're right to think that parsing is involved: when the filled-in input form arrives at the server, it has to be parsed to extract the text entered for each field in the form. However, that's all handled in low-level code that you don't have to think about. Instead, you can assume that, given the name of a field in the input form (e.g., 'locale'), there's a simple way to get the response text for that field (e.g., $RESPONSE['locale']).

Comment: Thanks Michael. Not being tech minded and to a large degree  unsure what the terminology is, I appreciate any thoughts and advice. 

Thanks once again James

Answer (score 0):

See [the Wikipedia article for 'Template processor'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_processor):

> A **template processor** (also known as a **template engine** or **template parser**) is software designed to combine templates with a data model to produce result documents.

In your case:

- the 'template' is the ebook that you write, with special markings at the points where the text depends on the user's input;
- the 'data model' is a particular set of values for the fields in the input form; and
- the 'result document' is the ebook that the user downloads.